# I have .aar file inside library module, how to use it in app module?

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, aar

I have .aar file inside library module, how to use it in app module, although I added this line inside the app gradle, please help me.

```
implementation project(":my_library")
```

Comment: Do you have source code of your .aar file ?? @Mahmoud Ibrahim

Comment: Yes, I have but I don't want to set it directly inside the module because the project is public

Comment: The classes inside nested .aar file (.aar inside module/lib) will not be accessible directly inside app. to achive this...

1. You have to upload your aar file to maven with pom file. see https://medium.com/@yegor_zatsepin/simple-way-to-publish-your-android-library-to-jcenter-d1e145bacf13
OR 
2.You can put all source code in module and obfuscate the .aar using proguard.

Comment: But, I forced to set the .aar file inside the library module not inside the app module because I want to publish my library to bintray to make users use it inside the their gradle

Comment: As you said that you have source code of aar file...do one thing
1. add that source code as other module into your app.
2. so your app now has two modules. compile and build your app as library project. (replace 'com.android.application' by 'com.android.library')
3. rebuild your project and use that final aar. into other projects

Comment: It can work only adding the aar file also inside the app module. Pushing the lib in a maven repo will not resolve the issue, because the aar file added as a flatDir repo in the library will not be published in the maven repo.

Answer (score 1):

Implement that .aar file into app Module, This is the only way. Otherwise you can't access the file into .aar file from app module.

```
implementation(name: 'your aar file name', ext: 'aar')
```

Answer (score 0):

Call like this in your project

```
implementation(name: 'my_library', ext: 'aar')
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `implementation`, use `api`

```
api project(":my_library")
```

Using `api` allows the sub-modules to be accessible along with the library, whereas using `implementation` won't allow that.

Comment: Not work, I think because the .aar file  that inside libs folder of my library not be a sub-module

Comment: Well, then make it. You will need to use the aar file at least in one place. You cannot expect it to be automatically imported in your project without mentioning it anywhere. Either use it in the sub-module or in the main app module.